# jQuery - the moving banner works but not positioned right

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello Stack over flow,

I am really stuck here, i was wondering if anybody can help me.

(Please note - I am total beginner with this jQuery moving banners!)

I am trying to move away from these jQuery freebie softwares and just have a simple / basic jQuery banner without too many programming at the back-end of the site.

Have a look at the site - its on a test site.  The index page has the jQuery banner positioned wrongly. (the banner works fine - I am happy with that)  Its just not positioned correctly.

The other web pages its fine and positioned correctly as its from a jQuery freebie software.

I think I have done something to the css with the jQuery banner

http://www.jrdesign-website.co.uk/new%20jquery/

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your issue isn't with your jquery, it's with your CSS.

```
.slider {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: tPlummer, thats great thank you - I've just corrected it.  You can see it again on the test site.  If I want to go further, e.g. a slide effect with buttons etc would that be easy?

Comment: Your other pages look like a flash fallback.  They're not actually running on jQuery.  

If you alter your markup to include the class names associated with the slider, it should be expandable to the other pages.

If you want me to do it for you, that's not how this site works. :)

Comment: hello tPlummer, thank you for your reply message. I am a bit confused re the flash fall back... I have now redone the rest of the pages as to the index page. Please see the live version. Is that better? Also I have to work out why the jQuery banner does not work well in iE7.

Comment: IE7?  What kind of bollocks contract did you sign that you'd support IE7?